# Docker python client API copy

Tags: python, rest, gzip, docker, deflate

I am using Docker python client API 'copy'.
Response from copy is of type `requests.packages.urllib3.HTTPResponse`

Does it need to be handled differently for different types of file?

I copied a text file from container but when I try to read it using
`response.read()` I am getting text data mixed with binary data.
I see content decoders as

```
>>>resonse.CONTENT_DECODERS
>>>['gzip', 'deflate']
```

What is the best way to handle/read/dump the response from copy API ?

Answer (score 6):

The response from the docker API is an uncompressed tar file. I had to read docker's source code to know the format of the response, as this is not documented. For instance, to download a file at `remote_path`, you need to do the following:

```
import tarfile, StringIO, os
reply = docker.copy(container, remote_path)
filelike = StringIO.StringIO(reply.read())
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj = filelike)
file = tar.extractfile(os.path.basename(remote_path))
print file.read()
```

The code should be modified to work on folders.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, Docker Remote API still has no idea about it.

Answer (score 3):

Here my python 3 version with docker API 1.38, the `copy` API seems to be replaced by `get_archive`.

```
archive, stat = client.get_archive(path)
filelike = io.BytesIO(b"".join(b for b in archive))
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=filelike)
fd = tar.extractfile(stat['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting @Apr's answer for Python 3:

```
import tarfile, io, os

def copy_from_docker(client, container_id, src, dest):
    reply = client.copy(container_id, src)
    filelike = io.BytesIO(reply.read())
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj = filelike)
    file = tar.extractfile(os.path.basename(src))
    with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file.read())
```